# ISNEW and ISBLANK not working together in Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, visual-workflow, isblank

I am using PB to check if the Case record is new, and if the Account field is Not blank and a Case.Account.picklist__c has a Certain value then update priority.

SO, my evaluation criteria are -

```
AND (
ISNEW() ,
NOT(ISBLANK([Case].AccountId )) ,
ISPICKVAL([Case].Account.picklistA__c , 'ABC') 
)
```

If all these conditions meet, I am updating the case priority.

But, when I create a Case record, where Account is blank, It throws an error -  The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Account.piclistA because it hasn't been set or assigned.

Comment: Try adding a null check for field `picklistA__c ` before this line `[Case].Account.picklistA__c `. Its always better to add a null check for related table values before accessing any field value in process builder.

Comment: HI @RohitMourya, Tried below :- 


`AND (
ISNEW(),
NOT(ISBLANK([Case].AccountId )) ,
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(([Case].Account.Customer_Segmentation__c )))),
ISPICKVAL([Case].Account.Customer_Segmentation__c , 'Growth Partner') 
)  `

but this doesnt work .same error.

Comment: Seems like its a known issue (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177114/simple-process-builder-failing-with-error-failed-to-access-the-value-for-variab) For Picklist values to work you need to use `CASE`.

Comment: That helps. Thank you so much @RohitMourya